# Why do I need Django for a simple Hello World?

Tags: python, django

I guys:

Sorry to bother you but this isn't a question of laziness. I'm posting this question here, after googling without success.

I know how to program in Python, but my interest is in web development.

What I want is very simple:

1) One HTML file with a text box for write one name. The HTML file must have the classical 
<form action="GetData.py" method="POST"> (or GET)
2) One Python file (GetData.py) that reads the content of the text box and write something like:

*Hello <name in the text box>*

The problem is that all free web hosting services I found, don't allow this, and forced me to use one web framework (most of them Django).

I have read the Django docs and the first example start immediately using databases which I don't need.

Can someone give me a clue about what files I must configure and what configurations I must do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run a WSGI Python application on your webhost? If so, then you could use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Web.py](http://webpy.org/).

Comment: doesnt sound like he has a real one ... can you post some of the example hosts you are referring to?

Comment: @Blender: Yes, but I have no idea what is WSGI.

Comment: @Joran: I'm use the PythonAnywhere hosting, They have Django, Flask and web2py. I don't know how to use nome of them.

Comment: Nobody told you use a huge python webframework for writing hello world.

Comment: If you don't know then start learning. Among the 3 you listed, Flask is the simplest one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm most familiar with Flask, so here's a simple "Hello World":

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/say_hello/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
    else:
        name = request.args.get('name', 'Bob')  # Defaults to "Bob"

    return 'Hello {name}!'.format(name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And some tests:

```
$ curl -d "name=John" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/say_hello/"  # POST
Hello John!
$ curl "http://127.0.0.1:5000/say_hello/?name=John"       # GET
Hello John!
```

And here's a link to Flask's deployment page: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/. I'm not sure if it will be useful, so read up on how your webhost expects you to deploy your application.

Comment: +1 for Flask. Simple, and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). It does have a framework, but it's a pretty simple one. And you don't really need to use it, anything in pure python probably will work. Like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), a very simple web framework with which I think you can do exactly what you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Django is just the most widely used Web-Framework for Python. Now Django suggested runtime on deployment is WSGI. If you host supports it you can also run micro-frameworks instead. If Django is your "only" option for now I suggest you to skip the database part of the tutorial. The steps you could follow from the tutorial:

1. [Creating a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)
2. [The development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)
3. Jump directly to [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/) (completely), again ignore db/model related stuff here

Anyway, google "Django Hello World" and you might also reach your target. :P

Answer (score 0):

Flask, web.py or straight WSGI is your answer. The webserver python modules (like modWSGI) that plug into Apache or NGINX will also work with these more minimal frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple django way to do it; but you should really accept @Blender's answer as Flask (and others like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) and [web.py](http://webpy.org/)) are the right way to accomplish your task. As you'll see, the simple way in django is considerably more involved.

First, [download and install](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) django.

Then, start a new project and add a new app to it. Then create a `forms.py` which will hold your form:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject simple_foo
$ cd simple_foo
~/simple_foo $ python manage.py startapp form_processor
~/simple_foo $ cd form_processor
~/simple_foo/form_processor $ vi forms.py
```

In `forms.py` add this and save the file and close your editor:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your Name:')
```

Next, we create the view. Open the existing `views.py` in the `form_processor` directory and add this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from form_processor.forms import MyForm

def home(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       f = MyForm(request.POST)
       if f.is_valid():
          return render(request,'results.html',{'result':f.cleaned_data['name']})
       else:
          return render(request,'index.html',{'form': f})
   else:
       return render(request,'index.html',{'form':MyForm()})
```

Finally, create your templates. Create a directory called `templates` in `form_processor`. In this directory, create a `results.html` and in it type `You entered {{ result }}` and save the file. Create another `index.html` and in it add:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

At this point, your application is done. The next steps tell django about your application and wire it to a url.

In the `simple_foo/simple_foo` directory (that's not a typo, its there twice), open the `settings.py` file.

Scroll down to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and add your new application, it should look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'form_processor',
)
```

Close and save this file. In the same `simple_foo/simple_foo` directory, open `urls.py`. Uncomment the first line under `# Examples:` and change it to look like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'form_processor.views.home', name='home'),
```

Save this file.

Now you are done. The rest is to run the built-in web server:

```
burhan@sandbox:~/simple_foo$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4, using settings 'simple_foo.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Open your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and fill in the form.